# PostgreSQL timeseries range query

Tags: postgresql

I have an application in Sinatra using Postgres and ActiveRecord. I have converted the ActiveRecord migration to raw sql below:

```
CREATE TABLE "locations" (
  "id" bigserial primary key,
  "latitude" character varying,
  "longitude" character varying,
  "speed" integer, "course" integer,
  "agent_uuid" character varying,
  "recorded_at" timestamp,
  "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL,
  "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL
)

CREATE  INDEX  "index_locations_on_agent_uuid_and_recorded_at" ON "locations"  ("agent_uuid", "recorded_at")
CREATE  INDEX  "index_locations_on_recorded_at" ON "locations"  ("recorded_at")
```

The table has 4m+ rows of user locations being pinged from mobile phones. I want to return the last 5 minutes of locations for all users. The query is taking 5+ seconds to complete which is too long, I would ideally like to get this under 0.5s.

I'm querying the db table with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    locations as l 
  WHERE 
    l.recorded_at >= (DATE '2017-10-20') 
    AND l.recorded_at < (DATE '2017-10-28') 
  ORDER BY 
    recorded_at DESC;
```

Running EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE BUFFERS it reports:

```
Sort  (cost=151034.25..151034.57 rows=126 width=85) (actual time=5609.589..5609.662 rows=253 loops=1)
  Output: id, latitude, longitude, speed, course, agent_uuid, recorded_at, created_at, updated_at
  Sort Key: l.recorded_at DESC
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 60kB
  Buffers: shared hit=25051 read=49475
  ->  Seq Scan on public.locations l  (cost=0.00..151029.85 rows=126 width=85) (actual time=314.955..5609.469 rows=253 loops=1)
        Output: id, latitude, longitude, speed, course, agent_uuid, recorded_at, created_at, updated_at
        Filter: ((l.recorded_at >= '2017-10-28 15:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (l.recorded_at < '2017-10-28 15:05:00'::timestamp without time zone))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 5117974
        Buffers: shared hit=25051 read=49475
Planning time: 0.081 ms
Execution time: 5609.721 ms
```

However it is still slow. Does anyone have any ideas how to speed this up, I'm at a loss. Any ideas is much appreciated.

---

Once I ran the migration to index_locations_on_recorded_at, this significantly sped up the query. The report after this migration was:

```
Index Scan Backward using index_locations_on_recorded_at on public.locations l  (cost=0.43..522.07 rows=169 width=85) (actual time=0.040..0.188 rows=253 loops=1)
  Output: id, latitude, longitude, speed, course, agent_uuid, recorded_at, created_at, updated_at
  Index Cond: ((l.recorded_at >= '2017-10-28 15:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (l.recorded_at < '2017-10-28 15:05:00'::timestamp without time zone))
  Buffers: shared hit=235
Planning time: 0.157 ms
Execution time: 0.885 ms
```

Thank you for your help all.

Comment: Without executing `explain` difficult identify bottleneck in your query

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, I have converted the active_record migration to raw sql, and the query to sql without the ruby for datetime string parsing. I have also added the explain analyze.

Comment: The query itself only takes 17 **milli** seconds. If you see those 5 seconds in the frontend then it's your application that is slow when displaying 9363 rows.

Comment: thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. The production db has 4m+ rows, this query is fast for a seeded development db of 10,000 rows, but takes 5s in the production db. Perhaps Postgres struggles with the size of the db, and I need to check out something like aws elasticache as a temporary solution, or migrating to a higher performing db.

Comment: Then show us the execution plan from production.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I have updated the Analyze report for the production DB.

Comment: Could you double check that the `index_locations_on_recorded_at` index exists in production?

Comment: Hi @Eelke, checked, it hadn't run, woops. However, after running the query is taking longer. The db is a bit larger though. I've updated the analyze in the question with the latest run.

Comment: It seems your statistics aren't up-to-date. Does the plan change if you run `analyze locations` or maybe even `vacuum analyze locations`? (the second one will require and exclusive lock on the table though)

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your help. Bit embarrassing, I hadn't pushed the last migration to production. Once the index on recorded_at was implemented, it was waaay faster. It now runs in 0.885ms. Many thanks for all your help